# Using D3 In Vue/Without selectors?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, vue.js

I'm trying to implement a pie chart very similar to this: http://bl.ocks.org/dbuezas/9306799

I can follow along reasonably well; ie. I can just manually add these to my template:

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .append("g")

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "slices");
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "labels");
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "lines");
```

Out of these, I just created a piece of a template like this:

```
<svg width="200" height="200">
      <g :style="{transform: `translate(${width / 2}px, ${height / 2}px)`}">
        <g class="labels"></g>
        <g class="slices">
          <path
            v-for="(s, i) in slices"
            class="slice"
            :key="i"
            :d="s.d"
            :fill="s.fill"></path>
        </g>
        <g class="lines"></g>
      </g>      
    </svg>
```

However, when the code references that SVG object to apply data to/etc, I'm kind of at a loss for what to do:

```
var slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
    .data(pie(data), key);

slice.enter()
    .insert("path")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.label); })
    .attr("class", "slice");
```

I figured there'd be some d3 methods I could feed data to to get back the relevant `d/fill` information for each pie slice, but I'm not sure if d3 was meant to be used this way. Am I looking at this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What you do now is building the UI (SVG elements) twice, once with d3 (`.select()`/`.append()`) and once with Vue (the html template). That doesn't make much sense, so you'll need to find another way for Vue and d3 to cooperate.

Here's an example which uses Vue for the UI, and d3 for data processing:

https://bl.ocks.org/getflourish/8b3eeb3076bc3e20099de7f2ef9186b8